# Mathematica Error on KUBUNTU

Tags: kubuntu, mathematica

***Introduction***

I installed **Mathematica 7** on my latest **kubuntu(fully updated) from 2020 iso**. Then i installed latest updates and rebooted.

*****Error*****

Mathematica on command prompt gives this error and the desktop command launches its opening screen for a second and then crashes immediately.

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

(After typing Mathematica on command prompt)

*****Additional Note*****

MathKernal works fine.

I also checked **mathematica 8** from my friend and it works and launches correctly **but with several fonts missing(writing  letters(C,G and D) in place of "[" and "]"), with the un resizable welcome screen.**
Everything works fine on ubuntu 2020.

Kindly guide me on these issues.

Comment: Since Mathematica is commercial software, surely they would have a forum or technical support that could help you?  In my opinion, for paid software, they should provide support for something as trivial as installation and start-up...

Answer (score 0):

Well in light of mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125473/… I disabled system fonts by renaming /etc/fonts/conf.d file and voila, mathematica 7 start up without any trouble and mathematica 8 also showed correct fonts as in ubuntu.

I deleted file by matching pattern method in groups and discovered the culprit as "45-generic.conf" that contained "emojees font", which were the bug cause just as described in the above linked post.

This file is common to both ubuntu and Kubuntu but only affecting mathematica 7 and 8 in Kubuntu 2020.